# Split a Panel data into groups

Tags: r, split

Let's say I have an unbalanced data frame in panel data format:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
Year <- c(2001,2002,2003,2001,2002,2001,2002,2003,2002,2003)
Observ <- c(0,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,1,2)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID,Year,Observ))

ID Year  Observ.
1   2001  0
1   2002  1
1   2003  1
2   2001  0
2   2002  0
3   2001  2
3   2002  2
3   2003  2
4   2002  1 
4   2003  2
```

What I would like to do is split the dataframe (using split, that's easy enough) but here's the catch: I would like each chunk to not divide the IDs, i.e, a break
by ID that chunks together more than one individual, but without breaking their temporal continuity. Something like

```
$1
Year  Observ.
1   2001  0
1   2002  1
1   2003  1
2   2001  0
2   2002  0

$2
Year  Observ.
3   2001  2
3   2002  2
3   2003  2
4   2002  1
4   2003  2
```

Any way of going about doing this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `split(df, (df$ID-1) %/% 2 + 1)`

Comment: Ok. can it be scalable? The real dataset has hundreds of thousands of individuals. Is it possible to have a method for having, say, 2000 chunks of 100 individuals each?

Comment: The `%/%` is fast.  You can check it by yourself  If it 100, then change the 2 to 100

Comment: Cheers. And what about if the field to divide on (ID) is not numeric? Ideally I would like not to convert it into factor. Any way of saying "this number of temporally chunked observations" into each division?

Comment: I the 'ids' are a combination of letters, numbers, do a `match` i.e. `ind <-match(df$id, unique(df$id))` and then do the `%/%` on that

Comment: Gr8! Actually it was even simpler than that, I just created a numeric identifier based on the factor one and grouped based on that. So simple that it eluded me! Thnks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do the `split` by creating a grouping variable with `%/%`

```
split(df, (df$ID-1) %/% 2 + 1)
```

---

If the 'ID' column is not numeric, then do a `match` on the `unique` elements to make it `numeric` and split on the matched index

```
indx <- match(df$ID, unique(df$ID))
split(df, (indx - 1) %/% 2 + 1)
```